# text processing: sed to work backwards to delete until string

Tags: awk, sed, text-processing

My AWK script generates 1 of the following 2 outputs depending on what text file it is being used on.

```
49 1146.469387755102 mongodb 192.168.0.8:27017 -p mongodb.database

1 1243.0 jdbc:mysql 192.168.0.8:3306/ycsb -p db.user
```

I need a way of deleting everything past the IP address, including the port number.

`sed 's/:[^:]*//2g'`

Works apart from the fact it deletes from left to right and as one of the outputs contains 2 `:` 's it stops and deletes everything after that. Is there a way of reversing sed to work from right to left?

Just to be clear, desired output of each would be:

```
49 1146.469387755102 mongodb 192.168.0.8

1 1243.0 jdbc:mysql 192.168.0.8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the below sed command.

```
sed 's/:[0-9]\{4\}.*//' file
```

OR

```
sed 's/:[^:]*$//' file
```

`[^:]*` negated character class which matches any char but not of `:`, zero or more times. `$` matches the end of the line boundary. So `:[^:]*$` matches all the chars from the last colon upto the end. Replacing those matched chars with empty string will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the greedy nature of the Kleene `*`:

```
sed 's/\(.*\):.*/\1/' file
```

The `.*` consumes as much as it can, while still matching the pattern. The captured part of the line is used in the replacement.

Alternatively, using awk (thanks to [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) for setting me straight):

```
awk -F: -v OFS=: 'NF{NF--}1' file
```

Set the input and output field separators to a colon remove the final field by decrementing `NF`. `1` is true so the default action `{print}` is performed. The `NF` condition prevents empty lines from causing an error, which may not be necessary in your case but does no harm.

Output either way:

```
49 1146.469387755102 mongodb 192.168.0.8

1 1243.0 jdbc:mysql 192.168.0.8
```